# Do I have to disclose my dual citizenship when applying for a US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, dual-nationality

If you apply for a working visa to the US, but will be travelling and applying with your South African passport, must you disclose that you have a British passport as well?  It asks the question do you have nationality with another country.  I just don't want to complicate things so not sure whether to say yes or no.

Comment: The degree of additional complication caused by your having a British passport will probably be negligible at most.  Once you find out how much it is, you can help others in your situation by returning here, posting a question such as "how much more complicated is it to apply for a US visa if you have passports from two countries," and answering it.

Comment: Being a British citizen would probably only increase your chances, so, even if it is not required...

Answer (score 13):

**Yes, you should absolutely answer questions truthfully on immigration forms.**

Giving false answers on an immigration form is a criminal offense. The consequences if your omissions is discovered are much more severe than any problems you will get from admitting dual nationality, and can include revoking your visa and being banned from the US.

It's very unlikely that having British nationality will negatively impact your application. Relations between the US and Britain have improved considerably in the last 200 years, they don't see being British as a negative.

Comment: Please cite the relevant criminal offense for lying on a USA immigration form.

Comment: Perjury? Fraud? Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course you have to disclose it. Honestly, how could you possibly believe otherwise?

If they find that you've lied on an immigration form, your visa will almost certainly be invalidated and you are likely to be banned from obtaining another visa in the future.